# unlink() deletes file but returns false

Tags: php, unlink

I have a problem and I can not solve it. I'm trying to delete a file and echo success messsage, but insted it deletes file but returns false. Here is my code:

```
if(unlink(".".MEDIA_PATH."/$av")){          
    exit(header("Location: page.php?&msg=success"));
}
else{
    exit(header("Location: page.php?msg=fail"));    
}
```

DanFromGermany helped me! **The solution is: Do not use Windows to programm, use Linux :) The error was because I'm using localhost on Windows OS.**

Comment: If `unlink` fails, it will (if enabled) output an `E_WARNING` resulting in your header not being set (you can't set headers after you've output text). Use the absolutely horrible error suppression operator `@` to fix this behaviour (`@unlink()`). **Note: Use of `@` should be *very* limited!**. Also note that if `$av` is `../page.php` or another *relative* path you are giving access to delete the entire server.

Comment: Please verify whether your current error settings would allow you to see a `E_WARNING` in case there's one.

Comment: It gives me this error: Warning: unlink(../media/09.2014/1529759289.jpeg): No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\gal\user.inc on line 153...
But it deletes it from server.

Comment: What makes you think it's your code what removes the file? Symptoms suggest the file does not exist in the first place :-?

Comment: Are you sure you're not deleting it twice?

Comment: I'm sure, there is only one unlink() func in my file. Can it be problem with path?

Comment: I changed it to absolute path like C:\xampp\htdocs\test/media/09.2014/399003666.jpeg but it still gives me the same error. I put unlink() in comment and when I run the script the file is still there, but when uncoment unlink() it deletes the file and return false and warning message. I'm running this on localhost on windows.

Comment: u would need to use @ supression operator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed your code a bit.

Check for file existense first, then delete.

```
$file = '.' . MEDIA_PATH . '/' . $av;

if (file_exists($file)) {
    if (unlink($file)) {          
        header("Location: page.php?msg=success");
    } else {
        header("Location: page.php?msg=fail&reason=cannot-delete");
    }
} else {
    header("Location: page.php?msg=fail&reason=file-not-exists");
}

exit;
```

**Update:**

[`unlink()`](http://php.net/unlink) is known to fail on windows systems, sometimes.

Comment: Tried this in the first place and it does not work. It jumps to header("Location: page.php?msg=fail&reason=file-not-exists");

Comment: When I comment unlink() the file is on server and nothing changes, but when I uncomment unlink() it deletes file from server and gives me false error. I used your solution and the same thing happens. I'm 100% sure that nothing else deletes file.

Comment: @LukaRogovic I just noticed you are working on a windows system. Your best bet then is to use `@unlink()`. Not very nice, but it should be ok in this case.

Comment: I have Linux live server but working on Windows localhost. So that's problem? Thank you Dan :) I need to change my OS!

Comment: You could try to install a virtual linux machine on your windows host :-)

Comment: Just downloaded Ubuntu and I will try it, thank u Dan :) Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the file exists before removing it with "file_exists" function (the "unlink" might be called with two instances being invoked at the same time, but it does not matter for testing).

```
$filePath = "." . MEDIA_PATH . "/$av";
if( !file_exists($filePath) ) {
    echo "File does not exist: $filePath";
    exit(1);
} else if( unlink($filePath) ) {
    exit(header("Location: page.php?&msg=success"));
} else{
    exit(header("Location: page.php?msg=fail"));    
}
```

If the workflow is faulty and the unlink function is being called twice, you'll notice it easily.

You can also use xdebug with breaks to test your code.

Comment: That does not help. When I just call unlink() without anything it deletes file and returns false with error: "The file does not exists...".

Comment: If the first condition returns TRUE, outputting the error message ("File does not exist: ..."), of course the "unlink" will not be called, because the script ends with the "exit" function.

If that's the only "unlink" function used in your project and the file to be deleted existed before running the script, the "page.php" seem to be loaded twice: the first time the "!file_exists" succeeds and "unlink" succeeds, but the second time the "!file_exists" fails. This is my original hypothesis: ("If the workflow is faulty ...").

Is that piece of code used when page.php is called?

Comment: You can use "Inspect element" to check if "page.php" is called twice.

If you're using the Chrome browse: right-click (you should see the context menu), click "**Inspect Element**" and click the "**Network**" tab.

If it's not activated, click the "**Preserve log**" checkbox.

Refresh your web page to remove the file.

Click the "**Filter**" icon (the third one from the left, starting from the red circle) and search for "page.php".

Count the ocurrences: if my hypothesis is correct, they're more than expected.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution but it's not the best. If you have any please help me.

This is my solution:

```
$del_file=".".MEDIA_PATH."/$av"; 

// Deleting file from server
@unlink($del_file); 

if(!file_exists($del_file)){                
    exit(header("Location: page.php?&msg=success"));
}
else{
    exit(header("Location: page.php?&msg=fail"));   
}
```

It still gives me the error false on unlink() so I added @ operator on unlink() to mask it, but that's not what I want. Does it matter because I'm on localhost (windows) and not on live server?

It looks like func unlink() runs twice and the first time it deletes file and secund time it returns false error because it can't find specifed file.

Answer (score 0):

Luka Rogovic:

> It looks like func unlink() runs twice and the first time it deletes
>   file and secund time it returns false error because it can't find
>   specifed file.

Try this:

```
$filePath = "." . MEDIA_PATH . "/$av";

if( !filter_has_var(INPUT_GET, 'msg') ) {
    if( !file_exists ) {
        exit(header("Location: page.php?msg=fail&reason=file-does-not-exist")); 
    } else if( unlink($filePath) ) {
        exit(header("Location: page.php?&msg=success"));
    } else{
        exit(header("Location: page.php?msg=fail&reason=cannot-delete"));
    }
}
```

I believe the "page.php" is being called twice and "unlink" was being called twice.

The condition "!filter_has_var(INPUT_GET, 'msg')" prevents that from happening.

Nevertheless, you should understand why the "solutions" work:
use "Inspect element" from your browser to analyse the redirects and use xdebug to see if the "unlink" is being called twice.